# Match range of unary naturals

Tags: regex

I'm trying to understand recursive regexes better by writing a regex that matches a list of successive unary naturals.

**Input strings that should match:**

`,1,11,111,1111,`

or `111,1111,11111,111111,`

My idea was to match a number, put it in group 1, then match a comma and match group 1 again, add a one and put that in group 1 again.

I tried unsuccessfully to avoid infinite recursion with a look-ahead:

**My attempt (please ignore how it slightly doesn't match the problem specification):**

```
my $r = qr/
(?:
    (?(?=11)
        ( (?1) 1)
      | (1) 
    )
      ,
)*/x;
'1,11,111' =~ $r;
```

I used Perl's regex engine, but I'm open for solutions using features from other engines as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate the question, but this does not work as intended. Whilst theoretically all has been said. The formula "regex cannot count", however, does not fully apply to a number of regex engines out there. However, there are still limits.

In your example, I see a problem having a variable starting point. Ideally, you would like to start the pattern at any point, i.e. `^1,11,...`, or `^11,111,...`, etc. Unfortunately, to my knowledge that's not possible without additional (explicit) alternations.

Sticking with the original approach, I could only create a pattern that always starts at `1,...` (or `,1,...` optionally) using a [forward reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html#forward) in a repeated group:

```
,?(?:
    ( \1? 1) 
    ,
)+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hfpdSM/3)

Comment: Thanks for finding that out! I'd use a star instead of a plus on the group, so that it also matches ",", i.e. a singleton list with a unary 0.